# remove row based on value in python

Tags: python, csv, filereader, filewriter

I have some code that is reading in a csv file. The code then adds values in based on user input. The problem that I am having is removing entries that contain an invalid value. The particular invalid value will be M. I use M for missing in my csv file. So essentially what I want to do is have the user input beginning and ending months then have the code add up precipitation values. However, if the string should contain an M I do not want to include that row of data. For instance...partial sample included below.

```
Station,        Stat,       lat,      lon,      JAN,  FEB,  MAR,  APR,  MAY,  JUN,  JUL,  AUG  
Bainville 6 NE, 24-0408-06, 48.14065, -104.267, 0.10, 0.01, 0.12, 1.23, 0.02, 0.34, M,    0.00  
Brockton 20S,   24-1164-06, 47.5075,  -104.324, M,    0.08, 0.13, 1.54, 2.43, 1.23, 1.12, 0.9  
Cohagen,        24-1875-06, 47.564,   -106.7,   0.3,  0.37, M,    0.76, 1.55, 1.69, 0.35, 0.41  
Sidney,         24-7560-06, 47.36,    -104.47,  0.1,  0.21, 0.05, 1.21, M,    1.25, 2.75, 0.89
```

Now if the user were to select months jan through mar then what I would like to have happen is that the Brockten row (jan) and Cohagen row (mar) be omitted as the value is M. However if the user selected months apr through may then the row to be omitted would be Sidney.

I hope this make sense.  I know this post is very long already but I will include my code as well.

```
    ##################################################
import csv
import array
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 4
from time import gmtime, strftime
print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

# Create an unordered MON to column number dictionary and get user data
mdict = {'MAR': 11, 'FEB': 10, 'AUG': 16, 'SEP': 17, 'APR': 12, 'JUN': 14,
         'JUL': 15, 'JAN': 9, 'MAY': 13, 'NOV': 19, 'DEC': 20, 'OCT': 18}

month_start = raw_input('Input the 3 letter ID of beginning month: ')
month_end = raw_input('Input the 3 letter ID of ending month: ')
month_start = month_start.upper()
month_end = month_end.upper()
mon_layer_name = month_start + ' through ' +month_end
user_month = '[' + mon_layer_name + ']'
start_num = mdict[month_start]
end_num = mdict[month_end]+1
new_list = [['Station', 'Lat', 'Long', 'mysum']]

with open('R:\\COOP\\temp\\COOP_rainfall2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    filereader.next() # this is to skip header
    for row in filereader:
        #print row
        sta = row[0]
        lat = row[2]
        lon = row[3]
        tot = decimal.Decimal(0)
        for x in row[start_num:end_num]:
            print 'now in line 34 in code'
            if x == '': x = 0
            elif x == 'M': # I think this is where I need to do something just not sure how ot accomplish it.
                x = 0
                print row
            tot = tot + decimal.Decimal(x)
        if tot == 0: continue
        else: new_list.append([sta, lat, lon, str(tot)])

with open('R:\\COOP\\temp\\output.csv', 'wb') as csvout:        
    print 'Now in file writer code block'
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvout)
    for line in new_list:
          filewriter.writerow(line)

Rex = 'R:\\COOP\\temp\\output.csv'
Precip=[] #creating an array named Precip
inp = open (Rex,"r") 
for line in inp.readlines():
 line.split(',')
 Precip.append(line)
file.close(inp)
print 'End of code'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that need to be addressed before your code will work. I'm not entierely sure what you are trying to accomplish but here are some suggestions:

The mdict values are not correct for the sample data you have provided - JAN is in position 3 for your header row.

Ideally, you would proceduralize the lookup by parsing the first line of the CSV instead of throwing it away. You can try this...

```
header_row = filereader.next() # if the months might NOT be uppercase, fix that here...
start_num = header_row.index(month_start.upper())
end_num = header_row.index(month_start.upper())
```

After you have fixed that you can check for 'M' in the list and use sum() with a comprehension to do the addition. Since I'm not sure how you want to handle the "good" rows I'll give a sense of where you can look for an answer...

```
# first, see if 'M' is any of the values in the range you are looking for
if 'M' in row[start_num:end_num]:
    # skip this row
    pass
# if 'M' is not one of the values, do the math with a built in function instead of
#   writing the loop yourself (this uses a comprehension too... that is a replacement for your loop.
else:
    total = sum( (decimal.Decimal(x) for x in row[start_num:end_num]))
```

Clarify your needs a little and I may be able to help you more...

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm if some cell contains a float (valid)  rather than a character with code like below:

```
def is_number(s):
try:
    float(s) # for int, long and float
    return true
except ValueError:
    return False
```

Once a "problem" row is identified you can remove that row via splicing, with code similar to below:

```
>>> print(a)
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 'M', 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
>>> problemRow =3 # would really use is_number here to identify row 3
>>> a[0:problemRow]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
>>> a[problemRow+1:] # nothing after the colon - extend to end
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
>>> b = a[0:problemRow]
>>> b.append(a[problemRow+1:])
>>> print(b)
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]]
```